# what does "throw your set" mean?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

In Seinfeld, season 9, episode 1, at around 17 minute.

> **KRAMER said to Seinfeld:** 
>   Jerry, what are you doing? George tells me
>   you're gonna **throw your set**?
>
> **Seinfeld answered:** 
>   That's right, Choochie. Let's see how Bania does
>   without the cushy time slot.

What does "throw you set" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To throw" means to [lose intentionally](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throw), often in the context of a competition.

A comedian's routine is also called a "set".

In the episode, Seinfeld is going to intentionally perform poorly, so that Bania, who performs after Seinfeld, will have to face a crowd in a worse mood.